# How to set SmartWatch screen brightness?

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

When I paint shapes on SmartWatch screen, the larger the area of white shape, the darker the screen. When it small white circle it's real white, when it's big it's gray. How to set that screen brightness was constantly maximum (real white)?

Answer (score 0):

In your control extension call `setScreenState`:

```
import com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.control.Control;
import com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.util.control.ControlExtension;

public class MyControlExtension extends ControlExtension {

    publid void example(){
      setScreenState(Control.Intents.SCREEN_STATE_AUTO); //the default
      setScreenState(Control.Intents.SCREEN_STATE_DIM);  //low bright
      setScreenState(Control.Intents.SCREEN_STATE_ON);   //full bright
      setScreenState(Control.Intents.SCREEN_STATE_OFF);  //off
    }

}
```

Comment: SCREEN_STATE_ON it didn't help, I try it. It just didn't allow to screen turn off.

Comment: Any difference at all between `ON` and `DIM`?

Comment: Brightness NO, just when DIM screen turn off after few seconds

Comment: Which version smartwatch is this?

Comment: version: SmartWatch 1

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all I could think of and didn't manage to get it done, so I think the correct answer is: it is not possible for the SmartWatch 1.

(It seems it some feature of the firmware which should protect the screen, or the battery life. Just a guess.)